# Configurar Spring Boot con dos DataSources

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Estoy utilizando **Spring Boot 2.X** con **Hibernate 5.X** para conectar dos bases de datos MySQL (Bar y Foo). Quiero poder listar las distintas entidades, con todos sus atributos (ID, Nombre y relaciones `@OneToMany/@ManyToOne`), de cada una de las dos bases de datos desde un @RESTController.

Consigo hacer el listado para la base de datos que tengo marcada como `@Primary` (en este caso Foo), sin embargo, cuando intento hacer el mismo listado para la otra base de datos (Bar) siempre obtengo una excepción al devolver el atributo `@OneToMany` (declarado como lazy). Si anoto la segunda base de datos (Bar) como `@Primary` en vez de Foo, obtengo el efecto contrario.
Existe una forma de resolver esto manteniendo los datos como Lazy?

Esta es la excepción que estoy obteniendo:

```
...w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver :
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: 
    Could not write JSON document: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: 
        com.foobar.bar.domain.Bar.manyBars, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-com.foobar.bar.domain.Bar["manyBars"]); 
    nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
        failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: 
        com.foobar.bar.domain.Bar.manyBars, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.foobar.bar.domain.Bar["manyBars"])
```

La configuración de la base de datos Foo:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.foobar.foo.repo"})
public class FooDbConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.foobar.foo.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("foo")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

La configuración de la base de datos Bar:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.foobar.bar.repo"})
public class BarDbConfig {

    @Bean(name = "barDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bar.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "barEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.foobar.bar.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("bar")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "barTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

Este es el controlador REST:

```
@RestController
public class FooBarController {

    private final FooRepository fooRepo;
    private final BarRepository barRepo;

    @Autowired
    FooBarController(FooRepository fooRepo, BarRepository barRepo) {
        this.fooRepo = fooRepo;
        this.barRepo = barRepo;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public List<Foo> listFoo() {
        return fooRepo.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/bar")
    public List<Bar> listBar() {
        return barRepo.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foobar/{id}")
    public String fooBar(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        Foo foo = fooRepo.findById(id);
        Bar bar = barRepo.findById(id);

        return foo.getName() + " " + bar.getName() + "!";
    }

}
```

Los repositorios:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
  Foo findById(Integer id);
}

@Repository
public interface BarRepository extends JpaRepository<Bar, Long> {
  Bar findById(Integer id);
}
```

Las entidades para la base de datos `@Primaria`. Las entidades de la base de datos secundaria son equivalentes (cambiando el nombre de las clases):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"foo"})
    private Set<ManyFoo> manyFoos = new HashSet<>(0);

    // Constructors, Getters, Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "many_foo")
public class ManyFoo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"manyFoos"})
    private Foo foo;

    // Constructors, Getters, Setters
}
```

Por último, el método main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Por favor agrega el código donde haces uso de los TransactionManager definidos para cada base de datos

Comment: He añadido el resto del código que estoy utilizando.

Comment: He encontrado la misma pregunta en [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424490/spring-boot-with-2-database-configs-lazy-loading-with-second-config-does-not-w), de momento también sin respuesta :(

Comment: Muchas gracias por el link. Estaré pendiente por ver si le responde algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad no sabría decirte porqué funciona la carga lazy con el `TransactionManager` marcado como `@Primary`, pero el problema que tienes es que estás retornando desde tu controlador REST una lista de entidades de JPA/Hibernate `List<Bar>`. El problema de hacer esto es que corres el riesgo de que cuando se intente trabajar con dichas entidades, como es el caso, hayan sido marcadas como `detached` ya que están fuera de una transacción. Como tu no usas la anotación `@Transactional`, la transacción muere con la llamada al método `findAll()` del repositorio y cuando SpringMVC necesita transformar las entidades a JSON para enviarlas al cliente, la entidad intenta cargar las relaciones marcadas como lazy y ahí se produce el error.

Para solventar esto, lo que te recomiendo es que (SIEMPRE) utilices una capa de servicios donde marques con `@Transactional` los métodos que necesiten realizar varias acciones sobre entidades. Debes tener en cuenta que al tener más de un `TransactionManager` tienes que especificar cual utilizar.

Este es un ejemplo de un servicio que permite obtener los listados de entidades.

Lo primero que voy a necesitar es una clase POJO por cada entidad.

```
public class BarDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private List<ManyBarDto> manyBars = new ArrayList();

    // Constructores, getters y setters
}

public class ManyBarDto {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    // Constructores, getters y setters
}
```

Ahora mi servicio.

```
public interface BarService {
    List<BarDto> getAllBars();
}

@Service
@Transactional("barTransactionManager")
public class BarServiceImpl implements BarService {


    private final BarRepository barRepo;

    @Autowired
    public BarServiceImpl(BarRepository barRepo) {
        this.barRepo = barRepo;
    }

    public List<BarDto> getAllBars() {
        List<Bar> barList = barRepo.findAll();
        List<BarDto> barDtoList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Bar bar : barList) {
            BarDto barDto= new BarDto();

            barDto.setId(bar.getId());
            barDto.setName(bar.getName());

            Set<ManyBar> manyBarList = bar.getManyBars();
            for (ManyBar manyBar : manyBarList) {
                ManyBarDto manyBarDto = new ManyBarDto();

                manyBarDto.setId(manyBar.getId());
                manyBarDto.setName(manyBar.getName);

                barDto.getManyBars().add(manyBarDto);
            }

            barDtoList.add(barDto);
        }

        return barDtoList;
    }
}
```

Entonce en el controlador REST utilizaríamos el servicio en vez del repositorio.

```
@RestController
public class FooBarController {

    private final BarService barService;

    @Autowired
    FooBarController(BarService barService) {
        this.barService = barService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/bar")
    public List<BarDto> listBar() {
        return barService.getAllBars();
    }

    // Resto de métodos
}
```

Esta es la forma recomendable de trabajar, para tener el código bien organizado, para que cada clase tenga una responsabilidad clara y para evitar errores como el que tienes. Es un MUY mala práctica que las entidades sean manipuladas en varias capas de la aplicación, y es lo que haces al retornarlas desde tus controladores REST.

Espero que con esto puedas resolver tu problema, y como te dije anteriormente, no tengo idea de porqué funciona con `@Primary`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
He estado echándole un vistazo y el problema que veo es que no se mantiene la propiedad Lazy de los atributos de Bar, ya que al crear el BarDto en el servicio estás recorriendo los objetos ManyBar. Esto sería algo que me interesaría mantener si fuera posible.

Comment: Es IMPOSIBLE mantener la propiedad carga lazy fuera de la capa de negocio, puesto que esta característica la brinda el framework ORM para evitar realizar consultas innecesarias a datos que no vas a utilizar. Puesto que si al final lo que quieres es enviar los datos de la entidad hacia el cliente, incluidos los datos de los objetos relacionados, no tienes otra opción que traer todos estos datos de la base de datos y convertirlos a una cadena JSON (cosa que hace Spring MVC por ti).

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo por la aclaración, creo que me queda todo un poco más claro.